# Compile error for @elidable function with interpolated string as default argument

Tags: scala, string-interpolation, scalac, elidable

I'd like to write my own assert like:

```
import scala.annotation.elidable

object Util {
  // doesn't matter if true or false
  def someCondition(checking: Any): Boolean = false

  @elidable(elidable.ASSERTION)
  def assertSomething(checking: Any)(
    msg: => String = s"Something didn't check out for $checking"
  ): Unit = {
    assert(someCondition(checking), msg)
  }
}
```

This compiles well and throws AssertionError where appropriate.

However, if I try to compile with scalacOption "-Xelide-below MAXIMUM", I get the following error:

```
    exception when typing new StringContext("Something didn\'t check out for ", "").s(checking)/class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Apply
too many arguments (2) for constructor StringContext: (parts: Seq)StringContext in file Util.scala
scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError: too many arguments (2) for constructor StringContext: (parts: Seq)StringContext
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$ThrowingReporter.handleError(Contexts.scala:1402)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$ContextReporter.issue(Contexts.scala:1254)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.issue(Contexts.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typed1$27(Typers.scala:4648)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.reportError$2(Typers.scala:4648)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.onError$3(Typers.scala:4693)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4718)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4745)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5510)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5527)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:755)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5563)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5593)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5537)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5541)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.transformedOrTyped(Typers.scala:5774)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedValDefImpl(Typers.scala:2068)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedValDef(Typers.scala:2024)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedDefDef$6(Typers.scala:2260)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedDefDef$5(Typers.scala:2260)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedDefDef(Typers.scala:2260)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5475)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5526)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:755)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5563)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5593)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5537)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5541)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5624)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStat$1(Typers.scala:3075)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedStats$9(Typers.scala:3219)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3219)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTemplate(Typers.scala:1987)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedClassDef(Typers.scala:1811)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5476)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5526)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:755)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5563)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5593)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5537)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5541)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5624)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStat$1(Typers.scala:3075)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedStats$9(Typers.scala:3219)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3219)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedPackageDef$1(Typers.scala:5176)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5479)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5526)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:755)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5563)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5593)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5537)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5541)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5620)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer.$anonfun$transform$4(Erasure.scala:1237)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer.transform(Erasure.scala:1233)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer.transform(Erasure.scala:808)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ast.Trees$Transformer.transformUnit(Trees.scala:140)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Transform$Phase.apply(Transform.scala:30)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.$anonfun$applyPhase$1(Global.scala:423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:416)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.$anonfun$run$1(Global.scala:387)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.$anonfun$run$1$adapted(Global.scala:387)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$Lambda$267/586617651.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1417)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.run(Global.scala:387)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1427)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1412)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1407)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1501)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainClass.doCompile(Main.scala:24)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:55)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.main(Driver.scala:68)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Main.main(Main.scala)
error:
  unrecoverable error
     while compiling: Util.scala
        during phase: globalPhase=erasure, enteringPhase=posterasure
     library version: version 2.12.2
    compiler version: version 2.12.2
  reconstructed args: -Xelide-below 2147483647

  last tree to typer: TypeTree(class StringContext)
       tree position: line 9 of Util.scala
            tree tpe: StringContext
              symbol: case class StringContext in package scala
   symbol definition: case class StringContext extends Product with Serializable (a ClassSymbol)
      symbol package: scala
       symbol owners: class StringContext
           call site: package <root> in <none>

== Source file context for tree position ==

     6
     7   @elidable(elidable.ASSERTION)
     8   def assertSomething(checking: Any)(
     9     msg: => String = s"Something didn't check out for $checking"
    10   ): Unit = {
    11     assert(someCondition(checking), msg)
    12   }
error: scala.reflect.internal.FatalError:
  unrecoverable error
     while compiling: Util.scala
        during phase: globalPhase=erasure, enteringPhase=posterasure
     library version: version 2.12.2
    compiler version: version 2.12.2
  reconstructed args: -Xelide-below 2147483647

  last tree to typer: TypeTree(class StringContext)
       tree position: line 9 of Util.scala
            tree tpe: StringContext
              symbol: case class StringContext in package scala
   symbol definition: case class StringContext extends Product with Serializable (a ClassSymbol)
      symbol package: scala
       symbol owners: class StringContext
           call site: package <root> in <none>

== Source file context for tree position ==

     6
     7   @elidable(elidable.ASSERTION)
     8   def assertSomething(checking: Any)(
     9     msg: => String = s"Something didn't check out for $checking"
    10   ): Unit = {
    11     assert(someCondition(checking), msg)
    12   }
    at scala.reflect.internal.Reporting.abort(Reporting.scala:61)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Reporting.abort$(Reporting.scala:57)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.abort(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:762)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5563)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5593)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5537)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5541)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.transformedOrTyped(Typers.scala:5774)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedValDefImpl(Typers.scala:2068)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedValDef(Typers.scala:2024)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedDefDef$6(Typers.scala:2260)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedDefDef$5(Typers.scala:2260)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedDefDef(Typers.scala:2260)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5475)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5526)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:755)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5563)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5593)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5537)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5541)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5624)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStat$1(Typers.scala:3075)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedStats$9(Typers.scala:3219)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3219)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTemplate(Typers.scala:1987)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedClassDef(Typers.scala:1811)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5476)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5526)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:755)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5563)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5593)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5537)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5541)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5624)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStat$1(Typers.scala:3075)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedStats$9(Typers.scala:3219)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3219)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedPackageDef$1(Typers.scala:5176)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5479)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5526)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:755)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5563)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5593)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5537)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5541)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5620)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer.$anonfun$transform$4(Erasure.scala:1237)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer.transform(Erasure.scala:1233)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer.transform(Erasure.scala:808)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ast.Trees$Transformer.transformUnit(Trees.scala:140)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Transform$Phase.apply(Transform.scala:30)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.$anonfun$applyPhase$1(Global.scala:423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:416)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.$anonfun$run$1(Global.scala:387)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.$anonfun$run$1$adapted(Global.scala:387)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$Lambda$267/586617651.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1417)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.run(Global.scala:387)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1427)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1412)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1407)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1501)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainClass.doCompile(Main.scala:24)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:55)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.main(Driver.scala:68)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

Now, an easy workaround is to use concatenation instead of interpolation.
However, I'd still like to unterstand why this happens. Afaik, elide-below only removes function calls and does not change the elidable function itself, right?